# Using the result of lower_bound as a parameter for upper_bound (or vice-versa)

Tags: c++, lower-bound

lower_bound returns the minimum position in a sorted vector that an element can be inserted, without losing the sorted order property. upper_bound, the maximum. With this in mind, is there any edge case for which:

```
auto lower = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x);
auto upper = std::upper_bound(lower, vec.end(), y); // using lower, as opposed to vec.begin()
for (auto it = lower; it != upper; it++) { /* do work */ }
```

Would not perform as expected? That is, would not visit every element in the range [x, y), where x < y?

I wish to know if this optimization (albeit small) is actually viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - yes, it's fine.

---

For your original question (where both upper and lower bound were searching for the same key `x`), it's already built-in as [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Note especially the paragraph

> The returned range is defined by two iterators, one pointing to the first element that is not less than value and another pointing to the first element greater than value. **The first iterator may be alternatively obtained with `std::lower_bound()`, the second - with `std::upper_bound()`**.

---

For the edited question - `lower_bound(x) .. upper_bound(y)` with `x <= y`, the preconditions change slightly.

The original version only required that the input range is *partitioned* with respect to comparison with `x`. Now, we require that it be partitioned wrt comparison with both `x` and `y`. This is still more than satisfied by a total ordering though, so your sorted vector will work assuming your `<` is sane (ie, it provides the required strict weak ordering).

Comment: Apologies, I made a couple edits to the question that may (or may not ) change your answer. I'll check out this documentation right now, though.